# Is it possible to clean/move WindowBuilder auto generated code for spacing/components?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm currently using windowbuilder and was curious if there are any ways out there to move all the code windowbuilder generates for the components and spacing to a different class. Or just things that you guys do to make it look nice/less noisy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so but then WindowBuilder will not be able to modify the underlying code; you'll lost the ability to visually edit the composition.

Instead you should check out "Code Generation" preferences of WindowBuilder to make it less noisy/look nicer for you.